# JQuery Broken With Upgrade

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

So I have a script that moves widgets around from the NetTuts site but that uses version 1.2.6 of JQuery. I need to use a newer version because of other things on the site needing it. Can anyone tell me what it defunct in my JQuery to cause it to stop working.

Site is viewable here:

http://dev.evaske.com/HXWP/wp-content/themes/habboxv7/test.html

As you can see, the boxes aren't draggable at all but when I used v1.2.6 they were.

Thanks

Comment: Version 1.2.6 is very old, many features have been removed/changed from the jQuery and jQuery UI since releasing that version, you should read the docs and replace the old/deprecated methods/options with the new ones.

Comment: That'll take forever though surely with there being so many new versions? Is there not a way for me to see what isn't working anymore?

Comment: I think it is not that terrible, also old event handling API is still in place so it wont take that long

Comment: @Tenatious You should use one version. Do you want to check your code in every released version? of course not. Load jQuery 1.7.2/1.8 and JS console shows you what doesn't work and you can modify it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use jquery 1.7.2 with jquery UI.

Also looking through your code I dont see any script running on DOM ready etc.

Open your jquery.widget.js file and change the following way

```
jQuery(function() {

 .... all file content goes here ....

});
```

Comment: 1.7.2 as I said. you can use latest version of jquery UI though.

Comment: Still not working getting an error in the chrome developer view.

Comment: I just updated it to: $(document).ready(function(){
 
iNettuts.init(); }); Still nothing :(

Comment: If I stick the }); in front of the iNettuts.init() I get an unrecognised function error. If I stick it after, nothing happens still :(

Comment: you are putting it after , ie call init within the same scope as you define your `iNettuts`

Comment: Tried it in both places. It might just be me being extremely thick!

Comment: you are updating source code too often and removing call to init and link to jquery.widget.js file at all often. write here once you stop doing it and have actual exception or something related to version of jquery.

Comment: Got it working. Someone had posted on the blog in the comments what code needed changing for the latest version of jQuery. I probably should have looked there first. Thanks for the help though! :)